# Bigger SVGs better quality than smaller SVGs?

Tags: image, css, svg

Do bigger svgs contain more detail than smaller svgs? I mean, is it better to export bigger svgs for the web or tiny ones? I know small ones load quicker and dont lose any quality when resized but just wanted to know if there are any disadvantages over bigger versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a bit I would say. As stated [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/):

> This specification defines the features and syntax for Scalable Vector
>   Graphics (SVG) Version 1.1, a modularized language for describing
>   two-dimensional vector and mixed vector/raster graphics in XML.

- If your export program compresses included/referenced raster images then you will have some quality decrease, of course.
- For vectorgraphics only there might only be reduction in decimal places, which may be reduced up to a certain point without "visible" quality loss / change in detail.
- If you have only vector graphics and do not change the decimal places then a smaller svg export of your graphic should only remove redundancy and compress the code.

An example of optimization for the last case can be found [here](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/blog/svg-optimiser) and some more specific information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/minimize.html).

Comment: How small would be too small? Is there rule of thumb?

Comment: None that I know of, I am not an SVG expert. If you have rastered images included then you need to decide on the quality yourself. The answer to this is subjective. If you only have Vector graphics then i suppose you might reduce safely to 3 or even 2 decimal places if it is for web content. If you have exporters that only reduce redundancy and compress the code then there is no loss, whatever size you choose I think. [See here](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/blog/svg-optimiser) or [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/minimize.html) what these "optimizers" do.

Answer (score 1):

SVG is vectordata the size you export doesn't influence the quality at all. You can it resize later and you will always have the best quality your output medium (screen) can provide.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in quality... big or small...  the only difference you might be talking about is the amount of detail, which increases the actual file size and thus the loading time for the browser.  But the quality will always be good, no matter what size it is.

Answer (score 0):

A few things affect the filesize of SVG, but they all have to do with the number, complexity, precision and redundancy of the information described therein. For example, rect x="100" y="200" width="200" height="300" and rect x="10" y="20" width="20" height="30"  will be identical depending on the display size, even though the latter takes a four less bytes (if talking ascii) to specify. An SVG path, describing, say the boundary between China and Mongolia, that has 4000 coordinates in it (as the treaties defining those regions would probably specify) would be more bulky than one that only has 400 points, though the latter would be less precise. If the SVG is created by hand in a program like Illustrator or Inkscape, then there may often be redundancies in the output: gradients that are defined and never used,  points that are specified several times within a path like d=" 0 0 0 0 100 100 100 100 ..." -- Inkscape has a way of simplifying the output so it has a little less cruft and there is a piece of freeware that has been around for a decade or so that can help remove such cruft. Also programs tend to output far more decimals of accuracy than most people or software would ever need, hence rendering the underlying geometry less accessible to the visually impaired: drawing a rectangle with precision in femto-meters is probably a bit of overkill and takes up space in the output. Basically, though the other folks who have responded are right, generally a square is a square is a square and on that takes up 50 bytes of storage is better than one that takes up 50 kilobytes of storage!

Comment: however, im thinking on giving up on SVG because it is far too inconsistent (support and rendering wise) in our browsers... especially as a background image. I think people are far better off using bigger sized PNGs and scale it down accordingly. The quality itself would be identical or better than the SVG itself (firefox 19-30, chrome, opera, safari 5-7). Optimized the file size (if the image is not complex) wouldnt be worth mentioning. A simple image at 8000 px resolution would only be around 200-300 kb which shouldnt be an issue in 2014.